# CentOS 6 JBoss: "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: java, centos6, sslhandshakeexception, sslerrorhandler

I have a JBoss application [Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (**build 1.7.0-b147**)] running on a CentOS 6 servers that sends information to an external address and occasionally an error occurs as described below.

```
2019-11-25 09:37:04,919 INFO  [STDOUT] ERRO: boletoComercioEletronicoBB - Boleto: 30293750000040348
2019-11-25 09:37:04,920 ERROR [STDERR] **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**
2019-11-25 09:37:04,922 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,922 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1836)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,922 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,923 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,923 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1337)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,923 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,923 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,923 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,923 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:966)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,923 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1262)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1289)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1273)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:523)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1087)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at creacorp.financeiro.facade.BoletoFacadeBean.boletoComercioEletronicoBB(BoletoFacadeBean.java:4398)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor975.invoke(Unknown Source)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,924 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:46)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,925 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aspects.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:77)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptor.java:102)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:47)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,926 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:211)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessLocalProxy.invoke(StatelessLocalProxy.java:79)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at $Proxy3127.boletoComercioEletronicoBB(Unknown Source)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at creacorp.cadastro.struts.action.profissional.LeituraArquivoXMLParaConfea.lerArquivosXmlAtualizandoDados(LeituraArquivoXMLParaConfea.java:883)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:280)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:216)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:53)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,927 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:64)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:48)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:280)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1858)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:446)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:697)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,928 ERROR [STDERR] at creacorp.cadastro.security.AutorizacaoFilter.doFilter(AutorizacaoFilter.java:134)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,929 ERROR [STDERR] at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,930 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.valves.FastCommonAccessLogValve.invoke(FastCommonAccessLogValve.java:495)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,930 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,930 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,930 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,930 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,930 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,930 ERROR [STDERR] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,930 ERROR [STDERR] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,933 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
2019-11-25 09:37:04,933 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,933 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,933 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,933 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,933 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,933 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
2019-11-25 09:37:04,933 ERROR [STDERR] at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1319)
```

I tested the application on other CentOS 6 and 7 servers with **Java version 1.8.0_201**, the error only occurs on servers with version 1.7. Is that it?

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "Is that it?". But the error (i.e. PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)  looks familiar. It's usually an indication that your trust store needs to be update with the ca cert of the CA which signed the server certificate for the server you're trying to connect to.

Comment: Is there any default path of the certificates? In CentOS, jboss was installed on /usr/local/jboss-4.0.5.GA and there isn't path like "security\cacerts" inside of /bin or something like that.

Comment: For now, I tested the Java upgrade on another vm and solved the problem without having to configure the certificates. But anyway, I still wanted to understand how to configure the certificates so that future events don't happen.

Comment: The "certificatepath" does not refer to the directory path to your certificate, but the path from the server certificate up the chain to all the way to the CA certificate for the server certificate (server cert -> intermediate ca cert -> root ca cert). 

So, the cacert needs to be update with the newest CA and Intermediate certificates for the server certificate of the server you are hitting. 

I'm guessing that by upgrading the Java Version, you probably upgraded the CACerts and that's why it's working. Another way of fixing it would be to update just the cacerts.